# Relation of these limits: $\lim_{z \to 0} e^{\frac i z}$, $\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{Re(z)}{|z|^2}$, $\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{Im(z)}{|z|^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, analysis, multivariable-calculus, exponential-function

**Definition**: 1stly, each of the expressions $e^{\frac i z}$, $\frac{Re(z)}{|z|^2}$ and $\frac{Im(z)}{|z|^2}$ are given to be defined on the respective maximal possible subsets of $\mathbb C$. I think each maximal subset is $\mathbb C \ \setminus 0$.

**Conjecture**: I suspect $\lim_{z \to 0} e^{\frac i z}$ doesn't exist using the non-existence of either of the ff limits $\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{Re(z)}{|z|^2}$ (or $\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{Im(z)}{|z|^2}$), but I think it's not necessary to use both of the latter.

Proof:

1. I think $\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{Re(z)}{|z|^2}$ doesn't exist because of the same reason as in the $\mathbb R^2$ case:

   - Along $x=0$, $\frac{Re(z)}{|z|^2}$ is identically zero.
   - Along $y=0$, $\frac{Re(z)}{|z|^2} = \frac 1 x$, w/c does not approach anything as $x \to 0$ (and we have $x \to 0$ from $z \to 0$).
2. Similar for $\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{Im(z)}{|z|^2}$.
3. As for $\lim_{z \to 0} e^{\frac i z}$, we have $$e^{\frac i z} = e^{\frac{Im(z)}{|z|^2}}[\cos(\frac{Re(z)}{|z|^2}) + i \sin(\frac{Re(z)}{|z|^2})]$$ $$= e^{\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}}[\cos(\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}) + i \sin(\frac{x}{x^2+y^2})]$$

$$= e^{\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}}\cos(\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}) + i e^{\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}}\sin(\frac{x}{x^2+y^2})$$

Therefore, $\lim_{z \to 0} e^{\frac i z}$ almost definitely doesn't exist because each of its real and imaginary parts are composed of $e^{\text{does not exist}}$ ($\cos$ or $\sin$) ($\text{does not exist}$).

QED

---

**Questions**:

1. Did I make any mistakes?
2. If not, then what's going on here?
3. Why would we ever think $\lim_{z \to 0} e^{\frac i z}$ exists? There's too much evidence to the contrary.
4. **Guess for #3**: It is possible somehow that, say for the real part, both of these limits don't exist

$$\lim_{z \to 0} e^{\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}}, \lim_{z \to 0}\cos(\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}),$$

but then somehow

$$\lim_{z \to 0}e^{\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}}\cos(\frac{x}{x^2+y^2})$$
might exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here's my answer: I'll disprove limit for $e^{\frac i z}$ doesn't exist because the limit of real part doesn't exist.

2 parts:

Part 1. I don't think there's necessarily a relation.

I think it's wrong to say, based on [that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4269513/dumb-question-when-do-we-say-limit-of-product-doesnt-exist-because-just-becaus) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4269544/properly-arguing-for-basic-limit-laws-specifically-compositions) $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}e^{\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}}\cos(\frac{x}{x^2+y^2})$ doesn't exist because like...

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}e^{\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}}\cos(\frac{x}{x^2+y^2})$$

$$ = \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}e^{\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}}  \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\cos(\frac{x}{x^2+y^2})$$

$$ = e^{\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{y}{x^2+y^2}}  \cos(\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x}{x^2+y^2})$$

$$ = e^{\text{doesn't exist}}\cos(\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x}{x^2+y^2})$$

$$ = (\text{doesn't exist})\cos(\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x}{x^2+y^2})$$

$$ = (\text{doesn't exist})$$

because I think it's like saying $\lim_{x \to 0} x \frac 1 x$ doesn't exist because $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac 1 x$ doesn't exist.

Part 2.

Sooooo here's how I'll argue

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}e^{\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}}\cos(\frac{x}{x^2+y^2})$$ doesn't exist because

$$\lim_{\substack{(x,y) \to (0,0) \\ y=0}}e^{\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}}\cos(\frac{x}{x^2+y^2})$$ doesn't exist because

$$\lim_{\substack{(x,y) \to (0,0) \\ y=0}}e^{\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}}\cos(\frac{x}{x^2+y^2})$$

$$ = \lim_{\substack{(x,y) \to (0,0) \\ y=0}}e^{0}\cos(\frac{x}{x^2})$$

$$ = \lim_{\substack{(x,y) \to (0,0) \\ y=0}}\cos(\frac{x}{x^2})$$

$$ = \lim_{\substack{(x,y) \to (0,0)}}\cos(\frac{x}{x^2})$$

$$ = \lim_{\substack{x \to 0}}\cos(\frac{x}{x^2})$$

$$ = \lim_{\substack{x \to 0}}\cos(\frac{1}{x})$$

and then because $\lim_{\substack{x \to 0}}\cos(\frac{1}{x})$ doesn't exist.

Or do instead $x=0$ and $y \to 0$ to say

$$\lim_{\substack{(x,y) \to (0,0) \\ x=0}}e^{\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}}\cos(\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}) = \lim_{\substack{y \to 0}}e^{\frac 1 y}$$

Answer (score 0):

$e^{i/z}$ has an essential singularity at z=0 and hence the limit does not exist as z tends to zero by Cassorati Theorem on Essential Singularities.

Comment: i know essential singularity, but essential singularity is too high a concept right now. we already know $\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{Re(z)}{|z|^2}$ and $\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{Im(z)}{|z|^2}$ do not exist. how do i use this to explain why $\lim_{z \to 0} e^{\frac i z}$ doesn't exist?

Comment: note: updated post

Comment: note: added answer